# jQuery Validation - Validate only 2 fields from multiple required fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation Plugin on my form. I have multiple fields in my form like first_name, last_name, email and password. All need to be validated but at some point I only want to validate the first_name and last_name and ignore email and password.

I can validate 1 field like `$('#form').validator().element('#first_name')` but I want to validate first_name and last_name at the same time.

I can not use `$('#form').validator().element('#first_name') && $('#form').validator().element('#last_name')` because it'll only validate 1 at a time but I want to validate both.

Thanks in advance
Noman Ilyas

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I've searched a lot for related topic but could not find anything that's why I'm asking here. Obviously if I had already found a solution then I would not ask my question.

Comment: ***if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)***

Comment: `$('#form').validator().element('#first_name') && $('#form').validator().element('#last_name')` should work fine. Without seeing a full example of your code, we can't debug why it doesn't.

Comment: And I am sure your answer is in [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+validate+two+fields+together+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan no related question is there.

Comment: Then we do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is a jsfiddle of basic functionality http://jsfiddle.net/gypd1Lr2/

Comment: here if you click on submit, it'll validate first_name, last_name and email. Now at some point I only want to validate first_name and last_name and ignore email.

Comment: What's the issue in the fiddle? It works exactly as jQuery.validate should do

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jsfiddle is working fine. I'm asking if there is a way to validate only first_name and last_name when user click on button A and when user click on button B, validate all inputs first_name, last_name and email.

Comment: You need to ask the question better; better description of function, a serious attempt as solving it, and it needs to include a demo.  Nobody knows what you're talking about when you say *"I want to do XYZ but then at some point I want to do ABC"*... at what point?  As far as clicking a button and dynamically changing the rules, this has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: HINTS: Search words along with the jQuery Validate tag would be "dynamic, rules, add, remove" [Also read the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org). There you will find the `.rules()` method which is specifically designed to dynamically add and remove rules based on other events such as clicking a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your condition inside required. `required` take a function.

Example:

```
"email": {
  required: function(element) {
    if (YourCondition) { // Check your condition
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  },
  email: true
}
```

Comment: I used the ignore in validate() function when defining it. I set it to ignore elements which has ignore class and I added ignore class to the elements before validating them (which I don't want to validate) and it worked.